# How do I resample a Pandas dataframe containing datetimes without losing tzinfo

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I want to resample. One of the columns in the dataframe contains timezone-aware datetimes and I want the resampled dataframe to contain the maximum value of the datetime for the sample period. I am expecting the value in the resampled dataframe to still be timezone-aware.

For a timeseries, this works:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint
rng = pd.date_range('20150101',periods=30,freq='D')

ts=pd.Series([datetime(2014,1,1, tzinfo=pytz.UTC) + timedelta(days=randint(1,365)) for item in rng], index=rng)

>>> ts.resample('W', how='max')
2015-01-04    2014-10-09 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-11    2014-12-14 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-18    2014-12-18 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-25    2014-10-18 00:00:00+00:00
2015-02-01    2014-11-21 00:00:00+00:00
```

However, if I do the same thing with a dataframe, I run into problems:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([(datetime(2014,1,1, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)+timedelta(days=randint(1,365))) for item in rng], index=rng)
df.columns=['last_seen']

>>> df.head()
                            last_seen
2015-01-01  2014-11-15 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-02  2014-11-13 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-03  2014-03-06 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-04  2014-11-29 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-05  2014-11-12 00:00:00+00:00

>>> df.resample('W', how='max')
            last_seen
2015-01-04 2014-11-29
2015-01-11 2014-12-29
2015-01-18 2014-12-13
2015-01-25 2014-11-03
2015-02-01 2014-12-21

>>> df.resample('W', how={'last_seen': 'max'})
            last_seen
2015-01-04 2014-11-29
2015-01-11 2014-12-29
2015-01-18 2014-12-13
2015-01-25 2014-11-03
2015-02-01 2014-12-21
```

This is actually a simplified example of what I am trying to do, which is actually group by one column while resampling two others with different functions:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([(randint(1,4), randint(1,100), datetime(2014,1,1, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)+timedelta(days=randint(1,365))) for item in rng], index=rng)
df.columns=('id', 'val', 'last_seen')
df.groupby('id').resample('W', how={'last_seen': 'max', 'val': 'sum'})
               val                  last_seen
id                                           
1  2015-01-04   56        2014-04-01 00:00:00
   2015-01-11   44        2014-03-09 00:00:00
   2015-01-18   43        2014-11-02 00:00:00
   2015-01-25  135        2014-12-19 00:00:00
   2015-02-01  230        2014-11-12 00:00:00
2  2015-01-04    3        2014-11-30 00:00:00
   2015-01-11  139        2014-12-09 00:00:00
   2015-01-18  118        2014-07-02 00:00:00
3  2015-01-04   48        2014-08-26 00:00:00
   2015-01-11   77        2014-08-03 00:00:00
   2015-01-18  173        2014-12-19 00:00:00
   2015-01-25  158        2014-11-25 00:00:00
4  2015-01-04   17  2014-01-13 00:00:00+00:00
   2015-01-11  147  2014-02-07 00:00:00+00:00
   2015-01-18   86  2014-04-03 00:00:00+00:00
   2015-01-25  NaN                        NaN
   2015-02-01   70  2014-07-27 00:00:00+00:00
```

As you can see, some of the resampled `last_seen` values are still timezone-aware, but most of them aren't.

We can look at the actual records to see if the provide an explanation, but I can't see anything:

```
>>> df[df['id']==3].sort_index()
            id  val                  last_seen
2015-01-03   3   48  2014-08-26 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-06   3   77  2014-08-03 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-12   3   84  2014-02-10 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-16   3   89  2014-12-19 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-19   3   91  2014-08-30 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-20   3   49  2014-04-17 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-21   3    4  2014-03-08 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-24   3   14  2014-11-25 00:00:00+00:00
>>> df[df['id']==4].sort_index()
            id  val                  last_seen
2015-01-01   4   17  2014-01-13 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-08   4   54  2014-02-07 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-09   4   93  2014-01-20 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-18   4   86  2014-04-03 00:00:00+00:00
2015-01-29   4   70  2014-07-27 00:00:00+00:00
```

I have also tried using a lambda to add the tzinfo back, but it still doesn't work, so I guess the tzinfo is being lost later in the process:

```
df.groupby('id').resample('W', how={'last_seen': lambda x: max(x).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC), 'val': 'sum'})
```

Comment: This is a bug, I suggest assigning back the resampled series: `df['last_seen'] = df['last_seen'].resample('W', how='max')` to preserve time zone information

Comment: General comment for people who come here from search. Sometimes it helps to swap `1D` for `24H`. That change alone may not solve this question, but it has helped me solve a couple of things with resample when I was using frequency >= `1D`.